# My program is outputting a warning because of IOException?

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

How do you fix this warning: unreachable catch clause? I have seen people do catch IOException after FileNotFound and I don't know what is the problem.

public void run() {

```
    int count = 0; 

    try {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            scan.next();
            count++;

        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println(file + " not found"); 

    } catch(IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the code

```
} catch(IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

reason being the only exception thrown within your `try` block is `FileNotFoundException` and its a subclass of `IOException`. Further to trace the exception this should suffice :

```
catch(FileNotFoundException exception) {
    System.out.println("" + " not found");
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @nullpointer Anything inside the IOException still throws an warning and I want to be able to printing out a generic error message,  If there is an 
exception during the reading of a file.

Comment: @Bob though one can catch the generic exception i.e. `IOException`, yet that shouldn't be a good practice. In the current block of code, `new FileInputStream(file)` would only throw a `FileNotFoundException` given that `file` is a String.

Comment: Make sense now, will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The only exception thrown from your code, which is in the `IOException` family of exceptions, is `FileNotFoundException`. Since you have a catch block for it (specifically) already, the `IOException` catch block becomes redundant.

In others' cases, they might be doing something else within the try-catch that also throws a different exception in the `IOException` family (or perhaps throws `IOException` itself), so catching `IOException` makes sense. For instance, consider this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read();
```

If you wrap this in a try-catch block, you can catch both `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` and there won't be warnings. The second line throws `IOException` directly.

As can be seen [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l850), Scanner swallows any `IOException`s thrown by the underlying Stream during read. If you're concerned about handling problems with the reading of the file, you have two options:

a) Don't use Scanner but instead, some lower-level API like a Reader or an InputStream.

b) Once your `while` loop completes, do this (though it's a very uncommon thing to do):

```
if (scan.ioException() != null) { 
    throw scan.ioException(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to just removed the IOException instead.